# create an empty numpy array based and append existing array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to initialize empty numpy (E) array and then append selected rows from existing array(D) to the empty array(E). I couldn't initialize an empty array matching the dimension of D.How can i solve this.

```
E = np.array([ [ ] ])

D = np.array([ [20, 23 ], [19, 23],[19,22] ]) 

for i in np.where(index):  ## assume index value is ([0],[2])

    E = np.append( E , D[i] , axis = 0)
```

I am trying to achive below result:

```
E = ([ [20, 23 ], [19,22] ])
```

> Error: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Don't try to imitate list append with arrays.  Stick with `E=[]` and `E.append(D[i])`, and then make the array afterwards.  `np.append` is slow, and you really have to understand array dimensions in order create the right 'empty' array.

Comment: For the array append to work, `E` has to start as a (0,2) shape array, and `D[i]` has to be turned into a (1,2) shaped array.  Even I had to hunt-n-peck to get that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Don't use `np.append`

`np.append` creates copies of data. You will find it inefficient. It should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

#### Read into `np.array` and slice

Convert your tuple of single-item lists into a NumPy array and index directly:

```
D = np.array([[20, 23], [19, 23], [19, 22]])
index = ([0], [2])

E = D[np.array(index).ravel()]
```

Result:

```
array([[20, 23],
       [19, 22]])
```

Comment: Thanks jpp. you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Why initialize an empty array? You could just slice `D` according to your indices instead:

```
index = [0,2]

E = D[index]

>>> E
array([[20, 23],
       [19, 22]])
```